# Can't bind to 'show-close' since it isn't a known property of 'modal-header'; modal-header' is not a known element in angular 5

Tags: angular5

```
<modal #modal id="modalwindow">
<modal-header [show-close]="true">
Add New School Admin
```

and i am getting an error:

1. If 'modal-header' is an Angular component and it has 'show-close' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'modal-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

][show-close]="true">
Add New School Admin

"): ng:///AddNewSchoolModule/addSchoolInfo.html@102:18
'modal-header' is not a known element:

4. If 'modal-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
5. If 'modal-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

> [ERROR ->]
>   Add New School "): ng:///AddNewSchoolModule/addSchoolInfo.html@102:4
>   'modal' is not a known element:

6. If 'modal' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
7. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

> [ERROR ->]
>
> at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:706)
>
> at TemplateParser.parse (webpack->internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24882)
>   atJitCompiler._parseTemplate(webpackinternal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34835)
>
> atJitCompiler._compileTemplate(webpackinternal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34810)
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34711)
>
> at Set.forEach ()
>
> atJitCompiler._compileComponents(webpackinternal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34711)
>   at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34581)
>
> at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:695)
>
> atJitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents(webpackinternal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34580)

Thanks in advance

Comment: ** This is my appmodule.ts**                                                            `import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
@NgModule({
imports: [
BsModalModule
],
providers: [AuthGuardService,{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having to upgrade an application to Angular 5 and ran into this. The author's npm page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bs3-modal) shows the elements now have a `bs-` prefix and the `[show-close]` attribute is now `[showDismiss]`:

```
<bs-modal #modal>
    <bs-modal-header [showDismiss]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h4>
    </bs-modal-header>
    <bs-modal-body>
        Hello World!
    </bs-modal-body>
    <bs-modal-footer [showDefaultButtons]="true"></bs-modal-footer>
</bs-modal>
```